# I want to pass variale from URL to the input text filed

Tags: php, textinput

Hi I have a URL `http://example.com/sr_web/confirm_place/index.php?student=123456&surname=test&firstname=Bugsy`, I want the student, surname and forename to get displayed into my input text boxes by doing `<?php echo $_GET['surname']; ?>`

But value is not getting displayed. It is getting displayed if I remove the input box and only echo itself `<?php echo $_GET["student"]; ?>` within the `<td>`. But when I write the following:

```
<input type="text" name="student" id="student" value="<?php echo $_GET["student"]; ?>">
```

input box get displayed blank.

It is getting passed (I checked the source) but does not get displayed in the input box, can anyone help?

Comment: while adding the tag add your language tag also....

Comment: can you add the view code. The place where you are echoing $_GETs

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the value of the $_GET variable in the `value` attribute. You also want to run `htmlentities` when doing this.

```
<input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php htmlentities($_GET['surname']); ?>" />
```

Comment: +1 It is important to sanitize data coming from the outside (ex. GET) before putting it into HTML. `htmlspecialchars` might suffice though.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the source alone, you could have overlooked something. Do a

```
var_dump($_GET['surname']);
```

If the surname is not appearing somewhere on the screen, something is wrong.

Try to write something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $_GET['surname']; ?>" />
```

but *not* within php tags.

Comment: Value is passing within the php tag so why did you say not within the php tag. My input box loos exaclty the one you have written. but value is not getting displayed

Comment: I mean you should not nest php tags. Seeing some beginners do this. If it still is not getting displayed and var_dump() didn't help, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can imagine that would cause this would be an incorrect use of GET. Are you sure that you are using GET and not POST. Is the url displaying myurl.html?firstname=john&surname=smith

Comment: Hi Yes my url is like yours.it is myurl.php?firstname=sonia&surname=rah. i am using _GET, not _POST.